# how to move sprite texture using AndEngine (Android) GLES 2

Tags: android, andengine, textures

I have created texture with TextureOptions.REPEATING_BILINEAR option.
Now I need to continuously move the texture position inside the sprite in order to create sliding effect without changing of sprite position.

I tried

```
sprite.getTextureRegion().setTextureX(20);
```

without any success. It only works before the sprite was created.

How to correctly implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't move textures inside the textureRegion, if you want to make a movement effect you either create a sprite sheet and use animated sprite to get that effect or use parallax background if it was a background that you wanna move around